# design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync

Tags: kotlin

espero estén teniendo un buen día.

Tengo este problema en Android Studio cada vez que creo un nuevo proyecto, lo cual es raro a que tengo uno creado previamente y ese no tiene el mismo error, me he fijado que no aparece el "module app" en Gradle y la clase de Main Activity Está en una carpeta que según yo no es habitual.[image: Este es el error que tengo]

En realidad soy muy nuevo usando Android Studio y me gustaría que me ayudaran por favor, muchas gracias y buen día :).

Comment: Si el proyecto lo has descargado o clonado de github o algún repositorio al ejecutarlo se deberá de agregar todo

Comment: No, lo creé desde 0. Intenté crear otros y es el mismo problema.

Comment: Que versión de android studio estás usando y que plantilla seleccionas al crear los proyectos? Evidentemente hay un problema  en los archivos build.gradle. Deberías agregarlos a tu pregunta

Comment: Estoy usando Android Studio 4.2 y uso el empty activity como plantilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que hay un bug en esa versión del plugin de kotlin. La solución es corregir manualmente la versión de kotlin en el archivo build.gradle (Project). Busca esta línea

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"
```

y remplaza la versión por `1.5.0`. Debe quedar así

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
```

Te saldrá una advertencia de que la versión no coincide con la del plugin pero simplemente ignorala. Se solucionará en la próxima actualización del plugin.

Comment: ¿Eso dónde lo veo?, es que si estoy muy perdido, ya busqué tutoriales, pero no encuentro ninguno que me indique o me ayude a localizar ese archivo

Comment: Listo, ya lo hice y me fue de maravilla, muchísimas gracias!